# which software to use for cleaning up files and increase performance of a computer under ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is system cleanup/optimization needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81042/is-system-cleanup-optimization-needed)

i am looking for a sofware that would clean up registry , temporary and log files on ubuntu.
Is there an equivalent to the windows CCleaner freeware?
cheers

Comment: You should specify the problem you try to solve. There is no 'registry' to clean up for instance. If you computer is slow, you might need to uninstall stuff, but an automatic program will only get you so far with that. If you need more space you might want to check log and temp files, but if you don't, they're not really slowing you down much.

Comment: "registry , temporary and log files" if they exist they do -not- make your system slow.

Comment: Please be easy on new users. He never stated unnecessary files are making his computer slow.

Comment: To the people who are voting to *delete* this question: Maybe consider asking for a merge instead? Not only does this have valuable answers, but [duplicate questions are considered often to serve an important purpose](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). While I'm pleased people are voting to delete old, off-topic/unclear posts with no useful information in them, I'm worried that some recently active delete voters may not be familiar with the reason most duplicates are not manually deleted. (Actually I think *nothing* needs to happen here, but a merge might be acceptable.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, there is no need of a cleaning software to speed up an Ubuntu machine. There is no registry in Linux and temp files are on `/tmp` directory which is not saved when you shutdown the machine.

Log files are on `/var/log` and have absolutely nothing to do with the speed of the machine (while they do not fill up the disk of course). Each log has several files because the old ones are compressed and a new one is created. The compressed (old) ones are usually in the form `/var/log/logfilename.#.gz`. Usually 2 files of each log are not compressed, the current one and the one before it (usually named `logfilename.1`). It is not needed and won't speed up your machine but if you need some small extra disk space, you can delete all the compressed ones if you don't need them (`sudo rm /var/log/*.gz` should work but you may need to do some adaptations depending on the names of your log files).

**A few little things you can do manually:**

Due to the package management automatic dependencies installations, you may have auto installed package that are not needed anymore. Remove them with: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Look at your swap to see if it is used heavily (not enough RAM):

```
free -m
```

The last line will tell you swap size, used and free. If use is high and you see on the above line `-/+ buffers/cache` that free memory is short, you may need to increase your RAM to speed up your machine. If swap is near 100% used, you need to increase swap space (but that is another question :) )

Browsers caches usually can be cleaned from the browser preferences.

Or as suggested in other answers, you can use Ubuntu Tweak! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

It let you clean cache from browsers, packages no longer needed, old kernel, and many more.

Comment: Oh, it seems we were typing at the same time and you came first :)

Comment: Why isn't Ubuntu-tweak in the official repos?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such thing as a registry in Ubuntu. You have a package index, package and config files, cookies, etc.

To clean up Ubuntu, you can use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

Also, take a look at [these tips](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920)

Hope it helps.