# CPU Temperature above normal (92 C)

Tags: 12.04, cpu, temperature

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and after running it on my laptop for few hours I decided to check the CPU temperature with `acpi -t` and it said **92 degrees Celsius**

When I ran windows 7, it always shows between 48 and 51 Degrees C, anyone know what might be causing this overheating problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend if you already updated the system with the latest packages (And also installed the proprietary drivers for your video card if it applies) installing **powertop**:

`sudo apt-get install powertop`

Then run it from a terminal like so: `sudo powertop`

It will show you what is using so much power. If you press the right arrow key and go to the last option called "Tunables" it should show you what optimizations you can do to lower the temperature.

[image]

Aside from powertop, there are also a couple of others like Jupiter and TLP. But those are better explained in this post: [Is system cleanup/optimization needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81042/is-system-cleanup-optimization-needed)